# Get parameters from anonynous class

Tags: java

is it possible to get the final parameter values from an anonymous class? Using reflection or anything else?

This example is of course all made up:

```
final String x = "Param1";
final String y = "Param2";
ITest<String> iTest = new ITest<String>() {

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return t.testMethod(x, y);
    }

};
// Get values or x and y from iTest here?
```

Comment: Sense.  You are not making any.

Comment: You can create instance variables to retain passed arguments.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Can you explain?

Comment: Let me put some code below. ITest is your own class right?

Comment: I think I understood you now. Is there no other way to do it? Yes, it's just a simple interface

Comment: So is this okay for your purposes KTrum?

Comment: Is `t` supposed to be `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is your code:

```
ITest<String> iTest = new ITest<String>() {

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return testMethod(x, y);
    }

};
```

Try defining `ITest` like so:

```
public class ITest {
    int x;
    int y;

    public testMethod(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }

    // execute somewhere
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. But there is no other way to accomplish this you think?`Without changing ITest

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but I believe that the values of `x` and `y` are copied into autogenerated fields in the anonymous class instance. Try this:

```
for (Field field : iTest.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.get(iTest));
}
```

Comment: I thought this too but sadly I only got the reference to the outer class which runs this code